# POSTGRESQL: Schema Does not Exists

Tags: json, postgresql, nested-groups

The following is my query:

```
select t1.id,
sum(
((t1.json->'group_te3dx03/group_tb3th42'->>1)::t1.json->>'group_te3dx03/group_tb3th42/number_of_seats_allotted_to_wo')::int +
((t1.json->'group_te3dx03/group_tb3th42'->>1)::t1.json->>'group_te3dx03/group_tb3th42/number_of_seats_allotted_to_me')::int 
)as number_of_seats

FROM table1 as t1 , table2 as t2
WHERE t1.xform_id = t2.id;
```

Here I have tried using nested groups with Alias name for Table1.

And while executing this query I get the Following error in PostGres:

```
ERROR: schema "t1" does not exist
SQL state: 3F000
```

I feel that the error might be due to the alias name 't1' used incorrectly for nested groups in Json.

Please help me make this query work.

Comment: Problematic part: `(t1.json->'group_te3dx03/group_tb3th42'->>1)::t1.json`. If you want to cast it to json use `(t1.json->'group_te3dx03/group_tb3th42'->>1)::json`.

Comment: Please post the structure of your JSON document. Only then can you get a proper solution.

Comment: @Radek Works like a cham..Thanks a lot...